# Twig template ignoring value in a for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, twig

I’m looking to ignore a value in an array, so that only three of the four children are displayed here. There are four items in the `page.root` but I only want to display three of them.

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      {% for child in page.root %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Looking through the documentation I can't find a way of limiting the `for` loop.

Thanks for the help!

============

Right, I was running Stacey app that also uses Twig. Sorry for that, I should have been more specific.

With stacey, slice is a method so this solves my problem:

```
<nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      {% for child in slice (page.root, 0,3) %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I found that [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/stacey/topics/slice_filter_in_3_0). This correctly outputs only three of the children in page.root.

Answer (score 0):

> *"The template system is meant to express presentation not program
>   logic." - Django documentation*

So, you can use if statment,

```
{% for child in page.root %}
  {% if child.title != 'any title' %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
  </li>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

[For the more information](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/if.html)

Answer (score 0):

The common solution for "printing only the first n items" is the [`slice`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html) filter:

```
{% for child in page.root|slice(0, 3) %}
    {# params are start and length, so that means the first 3 items #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It was added in twig 1.6, which version are you using (the most recent one is 1.12.1).

Comment: Never mind, just fixed the problem. I think I am running an older version but I don't want to mess with it as it's a part of the Stacey app. Thanks for the help though.